# Why would a method need a return value?

Tags: java, methods

Besides returning values for getter methods, I don't see the value in using return for my methods. In what other use cases would a return value be useful? Or, am I correct in assuming that you only need to return values for getter methods?

Comment: Primitives, builder pattern, factory methods, initializing methods... I'm sure many others I'm not thinking of

Comment: do you know what encapsulation means and why do we need that?

Comment: Go look at any code and look at what the methods' return is used for.

Comment: What about [`String.substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) or [`Math.round`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-)?

Answer (score 1):

Some setter methods have a meaningful return value.
For example, `Set`'s `add` returns `true` if the element didn't exist in the `Set` and was added.

Another example is the builder pattern, where each setter method returns `this`, which allows you to chain setter method calls:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClassBuilder().setA("a").setB("b").setNum(16).build();
```